# Android cursor columns

Tags: android, sqlite

Is is safe to assume that Android cursor only has the columns I requested and returns them in the same order as they are in the select statement, i. e. will the following code always work?

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("NAMES",
    new String[] {"FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "MOBILE"},
    "ID = " + requestedId, null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    firstname = cursor.getString(0);
    lastname = cursor.getString(1);
    mobile = cursor.getString(2);
}
```

or should I stick to getting column indices explicitly like below because Android SQLite may add some auxiliary data in the cursor returned by query() or change the order of the columns?

```
firstname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FIRSTNAME"));
lastname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LASTNAME"));
mobile = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MOBILE"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is is safe to assume that Android cursor only has the columns I requested and returns them in the same order as they are in the select statement, i. e. will the following code always work?

Yes, it's safe.

Under the hood it's just `SQLiteQueryBuilder` doing dumb string concatenation. You can examine the [source](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java) to learn more.